# Export Large mysql table into CSV laravel/php ~300k + rows

Tags: laravel, export, export-to-csv

I am creating a query application for users to filter several tables down and then download the results as CSV files, doing this with small return results has proven very easy, but several of the return datasets will be up and above 300k+ rows of data.

Time out errors were being thrown, so I need a new approach. Application is written in laravel.

I was able to run a raw query and created a csv with 380k rows of data, but the --secure-file-priv forced me to put the file into a specific place. I need the download file to be accessible to the user who filtered the data down.

my current 3 approaches as follows:

```
//        $performance = DB::select("SELECT * from performance_datas INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/performance_data2.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ;");
```

This raw query created the intended file, but I don't know how to make this accessible to the user to download.

Approach #2:

```
$headers = array(
        'Content-Type'        => 'text/csv',
        'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=performances.csv',
        'Expires'             => '0',
        'Pragma'              => 'public',
    );

    $response = new StreamedResponse(function() use($filename){
        // Open output stream
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');

        // Add CSV headers
        fputcsv($handle, [
            "id", "ref", "DataSet", "PubID", "TrialID", "TrtID", "SubjectID", "Site_Sample", "Day_Sample",
            "Time_Sample", "VarName", "VarValue", "VarUnits", "N", "SEM", "SED", "VarType"
        ]);

        PerformanceData::all()
            ->chunk(1500, function($datas) use($handle) {
                foreach ($datas as $data) {
                    // Add a new row with data
                    fputcsv($handle, [
                        // put data in file
                    ]);
                }
            });

        // Close the output stream
        fclose($handle);
    }, 200, $headers);
```

This approach timed out. I used Laravel to get ::all() in this case, this would be the largest data set for this particular table.

Approach 3 was just different variations of approach 2, with the same results of timing out.

I need the user to be able to create a csv and download it after its ready, or create and download it directly.

Open to any suggestions!

Comment: Is your mysql instance local or on separate server than laravel app server?

Comment: I am testing locally, but the mysql instance will live on the laravel app server

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/techsemicolon/laravel-query-to-csv) helps ?

Comment: @MihirBhende thanks for the suggestion, tried this also. this runs into access and permissions errors also. Not able to perform query: access denied